# A question about managing code repository structure - SO or SoftwareEngineering.SE?

Tags: discussion, scope

I asked this yesterday:

[Managing a complex repository structure - module dependencies and shared code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43170498/1593077)

I couldn't quite decide whether to ask that on SO or on Programmers.SE. Have I made the wrong call?

Comment: To me, it seems to be a bit too broad for SO.

Comment: I get the idea that the main hurdle is how to manage shared files, such as header files, in a version controlled way across different projects. The solution might be very different based on the tooling/platform you use and what A,B,C and D actually build into. I would rewrite to be as specific as possible.

Comment: @Gimby: ... but leave it here on SO?

Comment: If what I just claimed is correct then it seems on-topic for SO. Since its already here, might as well leave it here if you do know how to make it less broad.